# Why snprintf is not working for double 0x1p-1074 ...?

Tags: c, linux, glibc

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
        char *nstring = NULL;
        int n = 0, i = 0;
        double value = 0x1p-1074;
        char buf[128] = {0};

        n = snprintf(buf, 128,"%.*f", 8, value);

        while(i < n) {
                printf("buf[%d] : Data [%c]\n", i, buf[i]);
                i++;
        }

        return 0;
}
```

Here I am using `snprintf` to format the double `value` = `0x1p-1074` into `buf`. But when I execute the above code I get:

```
buf[0] : Data [0]
buf[1] : Data [.]
buf[2] : Data [0]
buf[3] : Data [0]
buf[4] : Data [0]
buf[5] : Data [0]
buf[6] : Data [0]
buf[7] : Data [0]
buf[8] : Data [0]
buf[9] : Data [0]
```

I tried using glibc function `fcvt_r` using `__snprintf()` as follows to format `0x1p-1074` like this:

```
 n = snprintf (buf, len, "%.*" FLOAT_FMT_FLAG "f", MIN (ndigit, NDIGIT_MAX),
                  value);
```

Can anyone explain the use of `FLOAT_FMT_FLAG`? I also tried replacing  `__snprintf()` with `snprintf()` in glib source (`misc/efgcvt_r.c`) and add some `printf`; that gives the output I expected:

```
buf[0] : Data [4]
buf[1] : Data [.]
buf[2] : Data [9]
buf[3] : Data [4]
buf[4] : Data []
buf[5] : Data []
buf[6] : Data []
buf[7] : Data []
```

This is the expected output. Can I use `FLOAT_FMT_FLAG` in my test program? Or is there any other way to get same output as given by glibc source code?

Comment: Why did you expect `4.94`?  The value is much smaller: `4.94066e-324`.  The output of `0.00000000` looks correct to me.

Comment: Is it significant that you're dealing with a subnormal value?  I'm assuming that your platform has the usual IEC 559/IEEE 754 floating-point types.

Comment: I am testing glibc test suit on our platform and a test **misc/tst-efgcvt.c(related to float to string conversion)** is failed on our platform, our platform support IEC 559/IEEE 754 floating-point types. On x86 also i am getting output 0.00000000,  I don't understand how glibc source giving output 4.94 on same x86 platform.

Comment: i am not aware of subnormal value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value `0x1p-1074` (the smallest possible subnormal value for IEEE-754 binary64 doubles, defined as `DBL_TRUE_MIN` in `<float.h>`) is extremely close to `0`. Printing with `%f` produces a decimal representation without an exponent, if you require only 8 decimal places, they will all be `0` and the output is as expected `0.00000000`.

you seem to assume that `%f` and `fcvt` should produce the same digits. It is true only for numbers between `1` and `10` in magnitude. For your example, `fcvt` produces the significant digits `4.94` but with a decimal exponent of `-324`.

`FLOAT_FMT_FLAG` is a non standard GNU extension to tell `printf` that the floating point value passed is a `long double`. Standard C defines this flag to be `L` since C99.

If your goal is to produce the output of `fcvt` with a C library that does not provide it, you can use `%.8e` and strip the exponent part.

Comment: Also FYI, 0x1p-1074 is DBL_TRUE_MIN, the smallest possible subnormal value for IEEE binary64 doubles.

Comment: I have used %.8e and got the expected output (4.94) with decimal exponent of -324 on x86 and on our architecture (9.88) with decimal exponent of -324. why both value are different , Do i need to check some factor that is affecting the result ?

Comment: @rdssonawane: That's interesting! Can you update the question with more info about your target environment.

Comment: @rdssonawane: are you talking about this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Socket_G2 the 988 pin socket for Intel core processors? They are x86 processors too, there should be no difference regarding the handling of `double` values. What compiler do you use? Or did you type `0x1p-1073` by mistake?

Comment: no sir, i am working on: [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SX-Aurora_TSUBASA ) its double-precision data format ①NaN if E = 2047 and F≠0
②(-1)S･∞ if E = 2047 and F=0
③(-1)S･2E-1023･(1.F) if 0 < E < 2047
④(-1)S･0 if E = 0 …… Signed Zero

Comment: compiler version is gcc (GCC) 7.1.0.

Comment: @rdssonawane: an awesome piece of hardware! There seems to be a glitch in its IEEE-754 support, either in the C library or in the hardware, which sounds unlikely, or possibly in the cross compilation environment... can you provide the contents of its `<float.h>` file?

Comment: @chqrlie sir i am really sorry, i can't share the contents of <float.h>  due to copyright issue. But i got one thing that our architecture doesn't support for subnormal numbers,The result is cut down to zero when an underflow occurs on the result.  Thank you very much for your support : )

Comment: @rdssonawane: can you at least post the definition for `DBL_TRUE_MIN` on that platform? Is the tool chain completely proprietary or does it contains ports of common open source packages?

Comment: @chqrlie sir, #define DBL_TRUE_MIN   ((double) 4.94065645841246544176568792868221372e-324L) .The complete tool chain is not proprietary. Some part are ports of common open source packages like "gcc" is ported version.

Comment: There seems to be a bug in the C library or an inconsistency between the headers and the library or faulty FP hardware. You mention problems in the support of IEEE-754 denormal values, which would explain your observations... not a good omen for a supercomputer contender.

Comment: @chqrlie sir, The tool chain is still in the development/testing phase. But i will surely try to mentioned this to my team member. Once confirm i will post here.